# Webkit (Chrome, Safari) browsers fail to update CSS after JQuery addClass

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, addclass

I built a small example of the behavior.  Basically, I have a page with an expandable pane on the left side.  When it expands, Chrome seems to fail to update the CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/HUHqA/2/

In this example, you click on the green rectangle which expands the left panel.  A css class is removed through JQuery to the panel on the right.  It appears that CSS class isn't applied until there's some kind of a layout action.  For example if you resize the page a tiny bit or if you open up developer tools and uncheck some random CSS.  When you do that action, the edge of the blue rectangle jumps to where it should be.

It looks like it might be related to the !important in one class overriding the other class.

Initially it has these two classes:

```
#main-content-right{
    min-width:200px;
    padding:0 15px 0 100px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    z-index:1;
    min-height:300px;
}

.main-content-collapse-right{
    padding:0 150px 0 29px !important;
}
```

Then the latter is removed.

If you uncomment the line in my hack function, that fixes it.  I basically have two questions.
1) Is this a bug in the browser itself? 
2) Is there a better solution than to just toggle some random css?

EDIT:  It looks like the answer to question 1 is yes: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93876 with simplified demo: https://bug-93876-attachments.webkit.org/attachment.cgi?id=158063

Comment: It works the same for me in chrome either way. Even removing the function `webkitHack`, it works the same.

Comment: There's a line in the actual hack function that is commented out.  It sets the padding to 9px.

Comment: Also of note, I had to change jQuery to 1.7.2 to get it to work on my home computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get rid of the `!important` by using this instead:

```
#main-content-right.main-content-collapse-right{
 padding:0 150px 0 29px;
}
```

With the id included, the specificity should be high enough that `!important` is unnecessary.

Comment: But if he does that it breaks the space between the elements.

Comment: Seems to have the same issue if I do that.